Unable to scrape the details of a property from a webpage using the requests module
I've created a script to scrape only the property details from a webpage using the requests module. The details are available in the page source, but I can't find any flag to capture them using regex. To be more specific, I wish to grab the content under Seneca Pointe details. Normally, the details are found in the summary block of the page source, but for this URL and a few others, they are different.
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.livabl.com/adelanto-ca/seneca-pointe1'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.livabl.com/',
}
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
try:
    details = re.findall(r'\\"summary\\":\{\\"value\\":\\"(.*?)\\"',r.text)[0]
except Exception as err: details = ""
print(details)

How can I get the property details from the webpage using the requests module?

requests cannot be used to scrape websites that utilize javascript to fetch the data. Either you need to see the actual endpoint where the data comes from and call that directly or use Selenium, Playwright or something similar that utilizes an actual browser.
